# Exercício URI 1012 - Wrong answer 20%

Tags: c++

Fiz o exercício, quase todas as saídas estão saindo como o output do URI estão pedindo, porém a primeira exigência não está como pede no programa. Usei o setprecision, mas estou na dúvida o porque o primeiro resultado não arredonda 3 casas decimais depois da vírgula.
a 3.0 
b 4.0
c 5.2

> ```
> TRIANGULO: 7.800
> CIRCULO: 84.949
> TRAPEZIO: 18.200
> QUADRADO: 16.000
> RETANGULO: 12.000
> ```

a minha primeira saída TRIANGULO sai apenas 7.8 e as demais saem perfeitamente.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double pi = 3.14159;
    double a, b, c;
    double area_triangulo, area_circulo, area_trapezio, 
    area_quadrado,area_retangulo;

    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

    area_triangulo = a * c / 2;
    area_circulo = pi * pow(c, 2);
    area_trapezio = ((a + b)* c)/2;
    area_quadrado = pow(b, 2);
    area_retangulo = a * b;

    std::cout << "TRIANGULO: " <<area_triangulo << std::setprecision(5)<<           
    std::fixed << std::endl;    
    std::cout << "CIRCULO: " <<area_circulo << std::setprecision(3)<< 
    std::fixed << std::endl;    
    std::cout << "TRAPEZIO: " <<area_trapezio << std::setprecision(3)<< 
    std::fixed << std::endl;
    std::cout << "QUADRADO: " <<area_quadrado << std::setprecision(3)<< 
    std::fixed << std::endl;
    std::cout << "RETANGULO: " <<area_retangulo << std::setprecision(3)<< 
    std::fixed << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) indica que as escritas seguintes serão feitas com notação de ponto fixo. A quantidade de dígitos mostrados depois da virgula é definida com [`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/).

Se pretende mostrar 3 dígitos depois da virgula deve utilizar:

```
std::setprecision(3);
```

Deve utilizar `std::fixed` e `set::setprecision` antes de escrever qualquer saída numérica e apenas uma única vez:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
std::cout << "TRIANGULO: " <<area_triangulo << std::endl;
std::cout << "CIRCULO: " <<area_circulo << std::endl;
std::cout << "TRAPEZIO: " <<area_trapezio << std::endl;
std::cout << "QUADRADO: " <<area_quadrado << std::endl;
std::cout << "RETANGULO: " <<area_retangulo << std::endl;
```

[Veja o resultado no Ideone](https://ideone.com/P9bEN3)

Comment: Obrigado Isac, em Python eu estava acostumado a fazer a formatação saída por saída. Agradecido irmão.